# Effective methods for fighting mining-related lag?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I love me some 5x3 embark areas; but as soon as I really cut into the bedrock; I quickly drop from 100/50 FPS to 25/15 FPS (exaggeration alert!). In fact, the most common cause of fortress abandonment for me isn't Goblin Sieges, it isn't lava-related Fun, it's not tantrum spirals, it's terrible lag, even when running a population cap of *20*.

From what I hear; it's more or less accepted that in the current version, the main culprit is mining and loose stone; and even turning all of the stone into constructions doesn't seem to help much.

Then again; building a playable fortress while staying squarely inside the three or four levels of soil on a "very deep soil" embark seems very undwarvely…

So how can I undertake massive digging projects and avoid terribletastic lag?

Comment: Atom-smash the stone, don't just use it to build constructions. Remove it from the stocks screen entirely.

Comment: I don't think there's a whole lot you can do actually.  Dwarf Fortress is inherently slow after a while.  If the stone doesn't make you slow, something else will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be well known (it's [mentioned in the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Maximizing_framerate)), but turning off the temperature and weather features hugely increased my framerate. Edit `data\init\d_init.txt`, find these lines:

```
[TEMPERATURE:YES]
[WEATHER:YES]
```

and change them to this:

```
[TEMPERATURE:NO]
[WEATHER:NO]
```

Comment: And additionally, make sure you don't have running water, whether that's due to cavern shenanigans, or worse.

Comment: That includes ocean/sea side embark sites, not just rivers! Waves/Tides will wreak havoc upon your FPS.